# How to stop a long running cmdlet in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Let's say I run this `cmdelt` :

```
C:\> Get-EventLog Application
```

This cmdlet takes forever showing events and never stops, is there a certain command or something I can type to stop it and return to my `C:\>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit Ctrl + C to break the cmdlet in process, returning you to the C: prompt.

```
Ctrl + C
```

Comment: `Ctrl + C` often fails to interrupt commands.
For example, `Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path '<some large file on network storage>'`.  The key-combo does work, but it takes maybe two minutes.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the environment you are working in.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works in the PowerShell console and ISE. I use the PowerGUI script editor and to achieve the same I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.